# Как решается вопрос о кэшировании?

Tags: php, http

Привет.

Вопрос по кэшированию. Кэшировать или нет - это определяется тем, что пришло в заголовке `HTTP`-ответа сервера. Есть 4 поля в заголовке `HTTP`, которые отвечают за кэширование и могут прийти в ответе сервера - `Last-Modified, Etag, Expires, Cache-control`. **Зачем аж 4 поля придумали?**

Видел, что могут в комбинации поля приходить в заголовке `HTTP`, например, L`ast-Modified + Etag`. **Зачем вообще комбинировать эти четыре поля (если можно обойтись одним полем из четырех вариантов)?**

Если одновременно использовать `Expires` и `Cache-control` (отправить их через функцию `header()`), то `Cache-control`  сильнее.  Остается две комбинации полей - `Expires + Last-Modified + Etag` и `Cache-control +Last-Modified + Etag`. **Как ведет себя браузер, если поля идут вместе?**

Answer (score 2):

`Last-Modified` показывает время последнего изменения документа, а что с этим делать - решать исключительно клиенту и только ему. Типичный сценарий использования этого заголовка:

- Сохраняем на клиенте эту дату
- При следующем запросе шлём серверу `If-Modified-Since что-сохранили`
- Если документ с этой даты не менялся, то сервер ответит `HTTP 304` и клиент может брать сохранённую копию. Иначе - сохраняет новую дату и обновляет документ в кэше.

`ETag` - фактически это некая контрольная сумма документа. Которая меняется при его изменении. Сценарий использования почти тот же:

- При первом обращении сохраняем значение `ETag`
- При следующих шлём `If-None-Match ...`
- На сервере отвечаем `HTTP 304` если значение то же, либо отдаём документ с новым `ETag`

То есть хоть эти заголовки и предназначены вроде бы для одного и то же, но содержат в себе разную информацию. Какой информацией, как именно и для каких целей пользоваться - решать клиентской стороне. Поэтому вопрос "Как ведут себя эти поля" некорректен. Поля никак себя не ведут, они просто существуют :) А что с ними будет происходить от сервера (отдающей стороны) уже никак не зависит. Обрабатываться они будут клиентом так, как он посчитает нужным для себя.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. согласен. поля себя вести не могут. не так написал. как эти штуки работают ПО ОТДЕЛЬНОСТИ, я тоже понимаю. вопрос был в другом - зачем столько полей ВМЕСТЕ кидать ПРОГРАММИСТУ (ведь именно программист их и кидает через пхп браузеру) в заголовке хттп, если для определения кэширования хватит и одного из них?

Comment: В HTTP/1 вообще много всякого :) Но в данном случае это разная информация. И есть много разных клиентов, которые по разным же причинам могут/хотят/умеют использовать что-то одно, например.